# Android - Can not share image in Facebook using ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-sharing

I could understand from various post that it is not possible to share both the image and text data in Facebook through intent share. But Twitter is able to share both thumbnail and text in Facebook through intent share which is shown in the image. SO can u comment on this and suggest a way to share both image and text in Facebook through intent.

Thanks in advance.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        intent.setType("image/*");


        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, viewProject.getShareLink());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "compatible apps:"));
```

[image: This is how it looks when sharing from Twitter]

Comment: why can't you use the `Facebook SDK` and share this through `ShareDialogBuilder`?

Comment: I want to post it in multiple apps as in share dialog,